# getting error while creating a hive table

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata

while creating a hive I'm getting the error like below, please any modifications/changes to resolve this error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTKk0.jpg)
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nFKf.jpg)

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.